# Recommended method for communicating with QuickBooks Pro 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I am attempting to integrate a web site with Quickbooks Pro 2012 and would like to know what the recommended method is as I'm having a hard time getting information from the Intuit site.

1. Can I use QBFC13 with Quickbooks 2012 or do I have to use QBFC12?
2. Since this is a website, I think the correct method is to use Web Connector, although the web server could have direct access to the QuickBooks company file.
3. I'm been looking for a recent Web Connector sample (one that doesn't use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Can I use QBFC13 with Quickbooks 2012 or do I have to use QBFC12?**

To my knowledge, all newer version of the SDK should work fine on older version of Quickbooks. I believe I read somewhere that they make an effort to keep it backwards compatible.

**2. Since this is a website, I think the correct method is to use Web Connector, although the web server could have direct access to the QuickBooks company file.**

I personally did not go with the webconnector route, because I needed real time comms. The webconnector will periodically "connect" to your website, and ask if it has any work for it to do. I personally created my own WCF Self Hosted service, which the website conencts to when needed. This wcf service, then interfaces with the quickbooks SDK, and passes the required info back to my website, when it wants it.

**3. I'm been looking for a recent Web Connector sample (one that doesn't
    use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB)**

Cant help you out here, although the QB specific stuff should generally still apply? Can't see why an example using a Jet DB would make the QB part of it unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either. You just need to make sure the QBXML version used is supported by QB.

Yes, you will need to use the web connector since this is going to a web site.